# SSE SIMD Optimization For Loop

Tags: visual-c++, sse, simd

I have some code in a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  u[i] = c * u[i] + s * b[i];
}
```

So, u and b are vectors of the same length, and c and s are scalars. Is this code a good candidate for vectorization for use with SSE in order to get a speedup?

**UPDATE**

I learnt vectorization (turns out it's not so hard if you use intrinsics) and implemented my loop in SSE. However, when setting the SSE2 flag in the VC++ compiler, I get about the same performance as with my own SSE code. The Intel compiler on the other hand was much faster than my SSE code or the VC++ compiler.

Here is the code I wrote for reference

```
double *u = (double*) _aligned_malloc(n * sizeof(double), 16);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   u[i] = 0;
}

int j = 0;
__m128d *uSSE = (__m128d*) u;
__m128d cStore = _mm_set1_pd(c);
__m128d sStore = _mm_set1_pd(s);
for (j = 0; j <= i - 2; j+=2)
{
  __m128d uStore = _mm_set_pd(u[j+1], u[j]);

  __m128d cu = _mm_mul_pd(cStore, uStore);
  __m128d so = _mm_mul_pd(sStore, omegaStore);

  uSSE[j/2] = _mm_add_pd(cu, so);
}
for(; j <= i; ++j)
{
  u[j] = c * u[j] + s * omegaCache[j];
}
```

Comment: [Note VC11 now uses SIMD in its optimizations](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/10/17/simd-optimized-c-code-in-visual-studio-11.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is an excellent candidate for vectorization.  But, before you do so, **make sure you've profiled your code** to be sure that this is actually worth optimizing.  That said, the vectorization would go something like this:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < n - 3; i += 4)
{
  load elements u[i,i+1,i+2,i+3]
  load elements b[i,i+1,i+2,i+3]
  vector multiply u * c
  vector multiply s * b
  add partial results
  store back to u[i,i+1,i+2,i+3]
}

// Finish up the uneven edge cases (or skip if you know n is a multiple of 4)
for( ; i < n; i++)
  u[i] = c * u[i] + s * b[i];
```

For even more performance, you can consider prefetching further array elements, and/or unrolling the loop and using [software pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_pipelining) to interleave the computation in one loop with the memory accesses from a different iteration.

Comment: Definately found this code as a bottleneck. A question to check that me learning and implementing vectorizing isn't a wasted effort - compilers won't generally automatically vectorize such code right?

Comment: @Projectile if you tell compiler about aliasing, generally it will.
From my own experience, it's very unusual to generate better code than compiler without very significant effort.

Answer (score 2):

`_mm_set_pd` is not vectorized. If taken literally, it reads the two doubles using scalar operations, then combines the two scalar doubles and copy them into the SSE register. Use `_mm_load_pd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

probably yes, but you have to help compiler with some hints.
`__restrict__` placed on pointers tells compiler that there is no alias between two pointers.
if you know alignment of your vectors, communicate that to compiler (Visual C++ may have some facility).

I am not familiar with Visual C++ myself, but I have heard it is no good for vectorization.
Consider using Intel compiler instead.
Intel allows pretty fine-grained control over assembly generated: http://www.intel.com/software/products/compilers/docs/clin/main_cls/cref_cls/common/cppref_pragma_vector.htm

Comment: who know Intel processor better than themselves ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a great candidate for vectorizaton, assuming there is no overlap of U and B array. But the code is bound by memory access(load/store). Vectorization helps reduce cycles per loop, but the instructions will stall due to cache-miss on U and B array . The Intel C/C++ Compiler generates the following code with default flags for Xeon x5500 processor. The compiler unrolls the loop by 8 and employs SIMD ADD (addpd) and MULTIPLY (mulpd) instructions using xmm[0-16] SIMD registers. In each cycle, the processor can issue 2 SIMD instructions yielding 4-way scalar ILP, assuming you have the data ready in the registers.

Here U, B, C and S are Double Precision (8 bytes).

```
    ..B1.14:                        # Preds ..B1.12 ..B1.10
    movaps    %xmm1, %xmm3                                  #5.1
    unpcklpd  %xmm3, %xmm3                                  #5.1
    movaps    %xmm0, %xmm2                                  #6.12
    unpcklpd  %xmm2, %xmm2                                  #6.12
      # LOE rax rcx rbx rbp rsi rdi r8 r12 r13 r14 r15 xmm0 xmm1 xmm2 xmm3
    ..B1.15:     # Preds ..B1.15 ..B1.14
    movsd     (%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm4                          #6.21
    movhpd    8(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm4                         #6.21
    mulpd     %xmm2, %xmm4                                  #6.21
    movaps    (%rdi,%rcx,8), %xmm5                          #6.12
    mulpd     %xmm3, %xmm5                                  #6.12
    addpd     %xmm4, %xmm5                                  #6.21
    movaps    16(%rdi,%rcx,8), %xmm7                        #6.12
    movaps    32(%rdi,%rcx,8), %xmm9                        #6.12
    movaps    48(%rdi,%rcx,8), %xmm11                       #6.12
    movaps    %xmm5, (%rdi,%rcx,8)                          #6.3
    mulpd     %xmm3, %xmm7                                  #6.12
    mulpd     %xmm3, %xmm9                                  #6.12
    mulpd     %xmm3, %xmm11                                 #6.12
    movsd     16(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm6                        #6.21
    movhpd    24(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm6                        #6.21
    mulpd     %xmm2, %xmm6                                  #6.21
    addpd     %xmm6, %xmm7                                  #6.21
    movaps    %xmm7, 16(%rdi,%rcx,8)                        #6.3
    movsd     32(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm8                        #6.21
    movhpd    40(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm8                        #6.21
    mulpd     %xmm2, %xmm8                                  #6.21
    addpd     %xmm8, %xmm9                                  #6.21
    movaps    %xmm9, 32(%rdi,%rcx,8)                        #6.3
    movsd     48(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm10                       #6.21
    movhpd    56(%rsi,%rcx,8), %xmm10                       #6.21
    mulpd     %xmm2, %xmm10                                 #6.21
    addpd     %xmm10, %xmm11                                #6.21
    movaps    %xmm11, 48(%rdi,%rcx,8)                       #6.3
    addq      $8, %rcx                                      #5.1
    cmpq      %r8, %rcx                                     #5.1
    jl        ..B1.15       # Prob 99%                      #5.1
```

Answer (score -2):

it depends on how you placed u and b in memory.
if both memory block are far from each other, SSE wouldn't boost much in this scenario.

it is suggested that the array u and b are AOE (array of structure) instead of SOA (structure of array), because you can load both of them into register in single instruction.

Comment: I disagree that using an AOS here will be advantageous over an SOA.  You're still doing 2 loads for every store, and with AOS you now have to write back only 2 out of every 4 units.  With SOA, you can load 4 units from `u`, 4 from `b`, and then write 4 back to `u` without needing to perform any shuffling or masking.

Comment: Disagree with YeenFei on both points. SOA is generally superior for vertical SIMD. Memory distance is not a relevant factor because of caching - even if the AOS permitted using fewer cache lines (e.g. because of extreme alignment padding, which is inherently unlikely to occur in a good candidate for SIMDization), it would still be better to restructure those cache lines to be SOA.